Assign values to a column based on patterns in another column
I have the following dataframe:
Sample <- data.frame(Sample_Name=c('502B_BCD_0TBC','0102_PER_2TBC', '0302_COR_0TBC', '0500_LN_TGHV'))<br />

I want to create a column "Sample_Type" based on multiple conditions:

if the Sample_Name has 'B_' or '_BLO' then Sample_Type should be 'BLO'
if the Sample_Name has 'PER' then the Sample_Type should be 'PER'
if the Sample_Name has 'COR' then the Sample_Type should be 'COR'
if the Sample_Name has 'LN' then the Sample_Type should be 'LN'
if the Sample_Name is not any of the above then the Sample_Type should be 'OTH'

Or something similar to the picture.
How could this be implemented?


Maybe just use a case_when() with grepl():
Sample |> mutate(Sample_Type = case_when(
  grepl("(B_)|(_BLO)",Sample_Name)~"BLO",
  grepl("_PER", Sample_Name)~"PER",
  grepl("_COR", Sample_Name)~"COR",
  grepl("_LN", Sample_Name)~"LN",
  .default = "OTHER"
))

Output
    Sample_Name Sample_Type
1 502B_BCD_0TBC         BLO
2 0102_PER_2TBC         PER
3 0302_COR_0TBC         COR
4  0500_LN_TGHV          LN


This worked perfect, thank you!

I suppose you could do it all with regular expressions:
library(tidyverse)

Sample %>%
  mutate(code = str_replace_all(Sample_Name,
                                c("^.*(B_|_BLO_).*$", "^.*_PER_.*$", 
                                  "^.*_COR_.*$", ".*_LN.*$"),
                                c("BLO", "PER", "COR", "LAN")),
         code = ifelse(code %in% c("BLO", "PER", "COR", "LAN"), code, "Other"))
#>     Sample_Name code
#> 1 502B_BCD_0TBC  BLO
#> 2 0102_PER_2TBC  PER
#> 3 0302_COR_0TBC  COR
#> 4  0500_LN_TGHV  LAN

